# Incorrect plot using pgfplots (trigonometric functions like cos, sin and tan)

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a function with pgfplots for LaTeX. Unfortunately, pgfplots plots the function incorrectly.  Here is the LaTeX code I use:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Gameplays,ylabel=Rating]
        \addplot+[gray,domain=1:30]
        {0.5 + 0.5 * ((atan(x) * 2 / pi)^11.79)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Omzetten van aantal gameplays tot impliciete rating}
\label{fig:omzetten_impliciete_ratings}
\end{figure}
```

Here is how the function should look like:

[image]

This is how it is plotted:

[image]

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Jan, welcome to tex.sx. Note that you original question was now [migrated to this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12953/2975). You might want to connect your stackoverflow.com account with your tex.sx account. You can do at your user page. I'm closing the other one for now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TikZ uses degrees instead of radians (yes, yes, I know ...).  So you need to replace `pi` by `180` (or, as Jake suggests in the comments, replace `atan(x)` by `rad(atan(x))`; the `rad` function converts degrees to radians).

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Gameplays,ylabel=Rating]
        \addplot+[gray,domain=1:30]
        {0.5 + 0.5 * ((atan(x) * 2 / 180)^11.79)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: PGFPlots with degrees]

which looks a lot more like what you want (the numbers on your graph are a little small for me so I compared with the output I get from gnuplot using your function and it looks right when compared with that).

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know pgfplots very well but it's possible to use gnuplot with pgfplots, no?

Comment: Or you can replace `atan(x)` with `rad(atan(x))`, which might be useful if you have more complicated functions and don't want to change all the coefficients.

Comment: @Altermundus: Nor do I!  But I've run into the radians/degrees issue with TikZ often enough that it was the first thing I thought of when I saw `atan` and it seemed to fix it.

Comment: @Jake: Yes, good point.  I'll edit that in as an alternative.

Comment: @Jan you might want to accept this answer, since it directly addressed your problem.

Comment: Alternative solution includes `sin((x)r)` → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30892/250119

Answer (score 15):

This is old but I found it when I had the same problem. Now there is a new solution called `trig format plots=rad`.

```
\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad]
...
```

See the manual section *4.3.3 Computing Coordinates with Mathematical Expressions*.

---

Just for search engines: pgfplots, trigonometric functions, radian, degree, wrong result, wrong plot

Comment: I just searched pgfplots wrong plot

Comment: Haha - cool coincidence :)

Comment: Remark, `\pgfplotsset` can be used to make this a default → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592675/250119

Answer (score 4):

Only for information. This is not an answer but I try your function with tkz-fct (tkz-fct works with tikz and gnuplot).

pgfplots is more complete and sophisticated package than tkz-fct.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=30,,xstep=5,
                 ymin=0.4,ymax=1,ystep=0.1]
        \tkzAxeXY 
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzFct[domain=1:30]{0.5 + 0.5 * ((atan(\x) * 2 / pi)**11.79) }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document
```

}

[image]