# Incorrect plot with pgfplots and LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect plot using Pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951/incorrect-plot-using-pgfplots)

I'm trying to plot a function with pgfplots for LaTeX. Unfortunately, pgfplots plots the function incorrectly.  Here is the LaTeX code I use:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Gameplays,ylabel=Rating]
        \addplot+[gray,domain=1:30]
        {0.5 + 0.5 * ((atan(x) * 2 / pi)^11.79)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Omzetten van aantal gameplays tot impliciete rating}
\label{fig:omzetten_impliciete_ratings}
\end{figure}
```

Here is how the function should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilXR3.png

This is how it is plotted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VQ5p.png

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Comment: there is a separate site for tex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: While I lament the fragmentation of SO vs programmers vs superuser vs unix vs ubuntu vs serverfault, having a single place for people to get help with TeX just seems to make too much sense.