# How to plot f(x)=sin(x), k(x)=cos(x) and u(x)=x² with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, boxplot

How can we plot the following three functions

- f(x) = sin(x)
- k(x) = cos(x)
- u(x) = x²

for x ∈ [0,1]

on a single plot with the help of TikZ?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: See also: [Incorrect plot using pgfplots (trigonometric functions like cos, sin and tan) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951/incorrect-plot-using-pgfplots-trigonometric-functions-like-cos-sin-and-tan) for `trig format plots` key etc..

Answer (score 38):

In pgfplots, you can implement the task with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1,legend pos=outer north east]
    \addplot {sin(deg(x))}; 
    \addplot {cos(deg(x))}; 
    \addplot {x^2};
    \legend{$\sin(x)$,$\cos(x)$,$x^2$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since the options are provided for the complete axis, the domain is shared among all these functions. The TikZ function `deg(x)` converts `x` from radians to degrees (similar to the postfix operator `x r` which does not appear to work in pgfplots).

The `\legend` describes the legend's values and the `legend pos` option is one of the prescribed ways to configure the legend.

[image]

You could also use `\addplot[color=red]` to configure color/marker and what-ever styles as discussed by Tobi.

Comment: Thanks for your addition! I was too lazy to give a full solution, but only because Mozo was too lazy to read the manual first himself …

Answer (score 17):

This is the example which can be fount in the pgfmanual.pdf on p. 225

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x)    node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
    \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
    \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.05*exp(\x)}) node[right]
        {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Think you can adapt it for your functions?!

There ist also a way with pgfplots. See the above mentioned manual for more information.

Comment: Hi, what does r do in sin(\x r)?

Comment: @The Imp r stands for radian (instead of degree)