# TikZ or pgfplots | Plotting a trigonometric function (cos / sin / tan)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to plot with `TikZ`/`pgfplots` the function f(x)=sin(\pi \cdot x)?

If so, how?

I want ti to look like the function here:
[image]

Comment: **(1)** This is clearly a *"Do-It-For-Me" question* in my opinion -- please show more effort. It is your *13th question*. **(2)** Here's one of many related already existing questions http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16232. **(3)** I edited the title of the question so that it is maybe more useful for others.

Comment: I barely know any `tikz` commands, and I tried doing a bit of coding that didn't work, like `\\addplot [blue, line width = 1, smooth, domain=-3:3] {sin(rad(\pi \cdot x)}; and some other ones.

Comment: Update: thank you, it helped - I discovered that I needed to use the `*` character for multiplication, and accidentally discovered that `pi` is the syntax for the symbol of pi (and not `\pi`, and I tried so far).

Please don't downvote the post.

Comment: Then provide a MWE and try `3.14` instead of `\pi` and `*` instead of `\cdot`. Don't mix LaTeX commands for type setting stuff with math commands for plotting stuff. Just have a look at the *pgfplots manual*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=4,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
     enlargelimits={abs=0.2}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-1:3,samples=50,smooth,red] {cos(deg(pi*x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I already found accidentally how to do it by the time you commented with a bit of help from the link that @Dr. Manuel Kuehner provided above.

Answer (score 2):

One possible:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}



% CORES DE GRÁFICOS
\usepackage{xcolor} % configurações de cor
\definecolor{padrao-grafico-grid}{RGB}{195,220,227}
\definecolor{padrao-grafico1}{RGB}{67,128,134}
\definecolor{padrao-grafico2}{HTML}{1ABC9C}
\definecolor{padrao-grafico3}{RGB}{243,156,18}
\definecolor{padrao-grafico4}{HTML}{c0392b}
\definecolor{padrao-grafico5}{HTML}{8e44ad}



% GRÁFICOS 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
        middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}





\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, grid=both, grid style={padrao-grafico-grid}, width=10cm, xtick={-1,0,...,3}, ytick={-1,0,...,1},
xmin=-2, xmax=4, ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2]

% gráficos de funções   
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,color=padrao-grafico2] (\x,{cos(pi*deg(x))});


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 



\begin{tikzpicture}
% remover grid - tirar grid=both, grid style={padrao_grafico4!15}, minor tick num=4
\begin{axis}[my style, grid=both, grid style={padrao-grafico-grid}, width=10cm, xtick={-3,-2,...,3}, ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4]

%gráfico com legenda
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,color=padrao-grafico1] (\x,{(e)^\x});
\label{plot_one}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{$y=e^x$}

% gráficos de funções   
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,color=padrao-grafico2] (\x,{\x^2});
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,color=padrao-grafico3] (\x,{\x});
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,smooth,color=padrao-grafico4] (\x,{2*\x});
\addplot+[ultra thick,mark=none,smooth,color=padrao-grafico5] (\x,{3*\x});

% pontos
\addplot[smooth,mark=x,color=padrao-grafico1] coordinates{(2,3)};
\addplot[smooth,mark=o,color=padrao-grafico2] coordinates{(2,2)};
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,color=padrao-grafico3] coordinates{(2,1)};

% assintota
\addplot[dashed, color=padrao-grafico4] coordinates{(-3,-4) (-3,4)};

% ponto com coordenada
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,color=padrao-grafico3] coordinates{(3,-3)};
\addplot[dashed,very thin,color=padrao-grafico4] coordinates { (3,0) (3,-3) (0,-3) };

\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(3,0)} node[pin=-50:{$(3,0)$}]{} ;

\addplot[mark=*,color=padrao-grafico4] coordinates {(2,-2)} node[right] {$A$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should increase the `samples` (200 is usually ok) to have a more relevant `sin` function.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     axis lines=middle,clip=false,
            xmin=-3,xmax=4,ymin=-2,ymax=2,
            ytick={-1,1},
            xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
            xticklabels={$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$1$,$2$},
            xticklabel style={black},
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$]
      \addplot[domain=-2:2,samples=200,orange]{sin(deg(pi*x))}
                                node[right,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$f(x)=\sin \pi x$};
      \addplot[domain=-2:2,samples=200,magenta]{cos(deg(pi*x))}
                                node[right,pos=1,font=\footnotesize]{$f(x)=\cos \pi x$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```