# Incorrect parametric pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I know that the equations (t-sin t, 1-cos t) define a cycloid that looks like this:
[image: cycloid]

However the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={Ciklois}, no markers]
\addplot[variable=\t, domain=0:360] ({t-sin(t)}, {1-cos(t)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives me this:

[image: wrong cycloid]

What's the problem? I know that `gnuplot` may help me out here, but I don't want to install it unless really necessary.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951 (\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad])

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing a wrong calculation, consider making like this (the `pgfplots` is confused with degrees and radians so):

```
\addplot[variable=\t, domain=-2*pi:2*pi] ({t-sin(deg(t))}, {1-cos(deg(t))});
```

[image]

**UPD:** Updated with the comment of **@ArTourter**. That's a better solution.

Comment: probably a slightly easier code to use would be to use the `deg` function provided by `pgfplots`: `t - sin(deg(t))`