# Graphing a sinusoidal function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to plot the graph for y = |sin(pi*x)| on the interval -2.5 and 2.5. (The graph is on or above the x-axis, and both ends are at height 1.)  TikZ plots a line through the origin.  The label for the graph should be to the right end of the graph - it can extend past the x-axis.  How to I add the label "x" to the x-axis and "y" to the y-axis?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=3,ymax=1.5,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-1:2,
          enlargelimits,
          axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          extra x ticks={-2,-1,0,1,2},
          %extra x tick style={grid=none}
]

\addplot[domain=-2.5:2.5,mark=none,samples=200] {abs(sin(pi(x)))} node[fill=white, below left, yshift=-3pt]{$y=\vert\sin(\pi x)\vert$};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
```

Comment: Add `xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$` to the options.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by percusse, adding `xlabel` and `ylabel` to axis options solves the label issue.

Another issue is plotting the correct function, which is solved by modifying the formula in `\addplot`. Note that `pgfplots` natively operates on degrees, so a conversion from radians to degrees by `deg()` is needed. Also an explicit multiplication must be done: `pi*x` instead of `pi(x)`.

**Edit:** Thanks to Jake for the comment that there is another way to use radians with `pgfplots` version 1.11 or later. Quoting the change log at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/:

> - new feature: 'trig format plots=rad' allows to use radians in trigonometric evaluations

So, if `trig format plots=rad` is added to axis options, `deg()` is no longer needed.

### Example using `deg()`

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=3,ymax=1.5,
          axis lines=middle,
          enlargelimits,
          axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          extra x ticks={0},
          xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
          clip=false,
]

\addplot[domain=-2.5:2.5,mark=none,samples=200] {abs(sin(deg(pi*x)))} node[fill=white, right]{$y=\vert\sin(\pi x)\vert$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since PGFPlots version 1.11, you can also [set `trig format plots=rad`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198126/2552) to avoid the need for the `deg` function.

Comment: @Jake Thanks. I wasn't aware of that option.