# TikZ code generated by GeoGebra improperly scales the plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to both `GeoGebra` and `TikZ` so my question might be silly.

I used `GeoGebra` to draw the distribution function of a Cauchy distribution, which is
`F(x) = 1/\pi \arctan(10(x-0.5))+0.5`.

Here is the plot I did in `GeoGebra`
[image]

and this is the TikZ code generated by the GeoGebra
[image]

or

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-0.6,0.) -- (1.6,0.);
\foreach \x in {-0.4,-0.2,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.,1.2,1.4,1.6}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
\draw[->,color=black] (0.,-0.6) -- (0.,1.2);
\foreach \y in {-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.,1.1}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
\clip(-0.6,-0.1) rectangle (1.6,1.2);
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.6:1.6] plot(\x,{1.0/3.1415926535* rad(atan(10.0*((\x)-0.5)))+0.5});
\draw [dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt,domain=-0.6:1.6] plot(\x,{(-1.-0.*\x)/-1.});
\draw [->,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (0.,0.688120318294) -- (0.568235782686,0.690599882462);
\draw [->,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (0.568235782686,0.690599882462) -- (0.57,0.);
\draw (-0.10792616721,1.20729312763) node[anchor=north west] {$F(x)$};
\draw (-0.0673181324647,0.722300140252) node[anchor=north west] {$U$};
\draw (0.534636264929,0.0039270687237) node[anchor=north west] {$X$};
\draw (1.47339847991,0.0112201963534) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw (-0.0553745928339,1.01767180926) node[anchor=north west] {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note.** I've add the function `rad` in front of `atan` as TikZ uses degrees instead of radians; see [the discussion here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951/incorrect-plot-using-pgfplots)

Finally, this is the plot I got after compiling the code in LaTex
[image]

What is the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you use `pgfplots` and plot?. However, put `,x=4cm,y=4cm` and adjust the anchors for nodes.

Comment: I have some more sophisticated plots to draw and would like to try some GUI first.

Comment: @WilliamZhang `pgfplots` allows you to draw fairly sophisticated plots.

Comment: @WilliamZhang By the way, did you forget to actually add the question to your post?

Comment: You're right. I've added the question explicitly. I'm not questioning the power of `pgfplots`. I just think its learning curve is steep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(note: I just noticed that my solution was mentioned before by Harish Kumar in the commnets)

The `tikzpicture` enviroment has options that allow you to control the scale (e.g. relative to the text size). Looks like the code generated by GeoGebra miscalculates this scale, even with respect to locations where it puts the labels.

I solved it by specifying these options `x=10.0cm,y=10.0cm`, as below. Now the result looks almost equal your GeoGebra window screenshot.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 

\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=10.0cm,y=10.0cm] 
\draw[->,color=black] (-0.6,0.) -- (1.6,0.); 
\foreach \x in `{-0.4,-0.2,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.,1.2,1.4,1.6} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt); 
\draw[->,color=black] (0.,-0.6) -- (0.,1.2); 
\foreach \y in {-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.,1.1}    
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt); 
\clip(-0.6,-0.1) rectangle (1.6,1.2); 
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.6:1.6] plot(\x,{1.0/3.1415926535* rad(atan(10.0*((\x)-0.5)))+0.5}); 
\draw [dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt,domain=-0.6:1.6] plot(\x,{(-1.-0.*\x)/-1.}); 
\draw [->,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (0.,0.688120318294) -- (0.568235782686,0.690599882462); 
\draw [->,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (0.568235782686,0.690599882462) -- (0.57,0.); 
\draw (-0.10792616721,1.20729312763) node[anchor=north west] {$F(x)$}; 
\draw (-0.0673181324647,0.722300140252) node[anchor=north west] {$U$}; 
\draw (0.534636264929,0.0039270687237) node[anchor=north west] {$X$}; 
\draw (1.47339847991,0.0112201963534) node[anchor=north west] {$x$}; 
\draw (-0.055374592`8339,1.01767180926) node[anchor=north west] {$1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
\end{document}
```

[image: scale10]

Answer (score 5):

Using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), the job is considerably simpler:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  samples=200,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  width=.8\linewidth,
  domain=-3:3
]
\addplot+[no marks,blue] {1/pi*atan(10*(x-0.5))+0.5};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] 
  (aux) at (axis cs:0.75,{1/pi*atan(10*(0.75-0.5))+0.5}) {};
\draw[dotted,->]
  (axis cs:0.75,0) node[below] {$x$} -- (aux);  
\draw[dotted,->]
  (axis cs:0,{1/pi*atan(10*(0.75-0.5))+0.5})  node[left] {$v$} -- (aux);  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Change 0.75 (which I used just for the example) to the desired value to locate the point on the path.