# tikz plot not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

The following code generates the wrong plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = 0:1, samples = 500]
    \addplot[color = black]  {pi/((pi/2)+atan(x/sqrt(1-x^2)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, for x tending to 1 the function tends to 1 and not to 0 as in the plot. See also

[plot on WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+pi+%2F+%28+pi%2F2+%2B+arctan%28x%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%29+x%3D0..1)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like: [Incorrect plot using Pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12951)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good old degrees vs. radians issue I think. `atan` in `pgf` returns degrees, while Wolfram Alpha probably uses radians.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = 0:1, samples = 100]
    \addplot[color = black]  {pi/(((pi/2)+atan(x/sqrt(1-x^2))*pi/180)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Plot it as a function:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = 0:1, samples = 500]
    \addplot[color = black] function {pi/((pi/2)+atan(x/sqrt(1-x^2)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works (+1), but uses `gnuplot`, so that is required, as well as enabling `--shell-escape`, so perhaps you could mention that.