# Plotting vector field with trigonometric function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the vector field $F(x,y) = \cos (x+y) \vec{i} + x \vec{j}$ using tikz. I followed another topic on plotting vector fields I saw here, used to plot some other vector fields and it went pretty well, but this one is driving me nuts. The goal is this

[image]

but instead I'm getting this

[image]

using this code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format = rad]
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
  view     = {0}{90},
  domain   = -1:1,
  y domain = -1:1,
  samples  = 21,
]

  \addplot3 [cyan, quiver={u={cos (x + y)}, v={x}, scale 
   arrows=0.1},samples=10, -latex] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I didn't even try to put the lines that represent the $x$ and $y$ axis. First I wasn't using `trig format = rad` and it wasn't quite right. Then I tried changing the $x$ and $y$ domain, but it only made it worse. Then I tried using `trig format = rad` but then I got this random line there and the vector field isn't even what I wanted. Can anybody give some help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You put in the wrong key → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198126/250119

Comment: @user202729 tysm! still not perfect but at least now I can work with what I have to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the arrow at center of grid coordinate, the `(x,y)` is subtracted  half the arrow length.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[rounded corners] (-3.2,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,3.2);
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm, y=1cm, z=0cm,
view={0}{90},
anchor=center,
trig format plots=rad,
xmin=-3, xmax=3,
ymin=-3, ymax=3,
axis lines=center,
domain=-3:3,
y domain=-3:3,
enlargelimits=0.1,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot3[
cyan, thick,
point meta={sqrt((cos(x+y))^2+x^2)},
quiver={
  u={cos(x+y)}, v={x},
  scale arrows=0.2,
  every arrow/.append style={-{Triangle[scale=0.2+0.8*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000]}},
},
samples=10,
] (x-0.1*cos(x+y),y-0.1*x,0);
\end{axis}
\draw[cyan, ultra thick, rounded corners] (-3.2,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,3.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quiver plot in a frame]

Edit: A more correct plot would be to calculate the arrow vector from this new position like in red below

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[rounded corners] (-3.2,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,3.2);
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm, y=1cm, z=0cm,
view={0}{90},
anchor=center,
trig format plots=rad,
xmin=-3, xmax=3,
ymin=-3, ymax=3,
axis lines=center,
domain=-3:3,
y domain=-3:3,
enlargelimits=0.1,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot3[
cyan, thick,
point meta={sqrt((cos(x+y))^2+x^2)},
quiver={
  u={cos(x+y)}, v={x},
  scale arrows=0.2,
  every arrow/.append style={-{Triangle[scale=0.2+0.8*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000]}},
},
samples=10,
] (x-0.1*cos(x+y),y-0.1*x,0);
\addplot3[
red, thick,
point meta={sqrt((cos((x-0.1*cos(x+y))+y))^2+(x-0.1*cos(x+y))^2)},
quiver={
  u={cos((x-0.1*cos(x+y))+y)}, v={x-0.1*cos(x+y)},
  scale arrows=0.2,
  every arrow/.append style={-{Triangle[scale=0.2+0.8*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000]}},
},
samples=10,
] (x-0.1*cos(x+y),y-0.1*x,0);\end{axis}
\draw[cyan, ultra thick, rounded corners] (-3.2,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,3.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: quiver plot with modified arrows]

Comment: What does ```point meta```mean? Everything else I think I understand.

Comment: `point meta` is just some extra user defined "coordinate". It can be used for many things. Here I use it to set the size of the of the arrow tip app. proportional to the length of the arrow.