# Evaluate rotation based on atan x

Tags: rotating, tikz-calc, atan2

I would like to express the angle of rotation for the tangent line in terms of atan x using the slope (which is calculated earlier in the problem). I can get it to work using the angle but I do not want to have to calculate it by hand first. I would like the black line to end up where the red line is using a calculation that's similar to the black line.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.4, yscale=0.1]
    
        % draw axis
        \draw (-1.5,0) -- (6.5,0);
        \draw (0,-10) -- (0,15);
        
        % plot f(x)
        \draw [domain=(-1:6)] plot (\x,\x*\x-3*\x-4);
        
        % plot secant line
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) -- (6,14);
        
        % plot tangent line
        \draw [rotate around={{180*atan(2)/pi}:(2.5,-5.25)}] (-2,-5.25) -- (7,-5.25); 
        \draw [red, rotate around={{63.43}:(2.5,-5.25)}] (-2,-5.25) -- (7,-5.25); 
        
        % plot cirles as points
        \foreach \x/\y in {-1/0,2.5/-5.25,6/14}{\draw [fill=black] (\x,\y) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.4cm);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

TIA.

Comment: By the way, there's a `atan2(y, x)` function that takes the quadrant in consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug the issue, just use `\pgfmathparse... \pgfmathresult` to print out the value of the formula, you'll see the problem immediately:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{180*atan(2)/pi}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

prints out 3634.56235 while you want some value around 63. Changing it to just `atan(2)` gives the desired result.

Explanation, TikZ uses degrees instead of radians by default for trigonometric functions → [Incorrect plot using pgfplots (trigonometric functions like cos, sin and tan) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12951/incorrect-plot-using-pgfplots-trigonometric-functions-like-cos-sin-and-tan).

Anyway, the fix is simply

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.4, yscale=0.1]
    
        % draw axis
        \draw (-1.5,0) -- (6.5,0);
        \draw (0,-10) -- (0,15);
        
        % plot f(x)
        \draw [domain=(-1:6)] plot (\x,\x*\x-3*\x-4);
        
        % plot secant line
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) -- (6,14);
        
        % plot tangent line
        \draw [rotate around={{atan(2)}:(2.5,-5.25)}] (-2,-5.25) -- (7,-5.25); 
        \draw [red, rotate around={{63.43}:(2.5,-5.25)}] (-2,-5.25) -- (7,-5.25); 
        
        % plot cirles as points
        \foreach \x/\y in {-1/0,2.5/-5.25,6/14}{\draw [fill=black] (\x,\y) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.4cm);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Admittedly it's *almost* a duplicate of the linked question... except for the use cases...?

Comment: @ user202729, thx. Sorry for the repeat question. I searched the forum as many ways as I could but never found anything.